# Lua How to create a table inside a function?

Tags: lua

I'm a beginner at Lua and programming in general (I've had some experience in other languages but nothing huge) and I've been following a tutorial where there's this one exercise on tables:

*"Make a function with a table in it, where each key in the table is an animal name. Give each key a value equal to the sound the animal makes and return the animal sound. Try invoking the function and see if you get back the correct sound."*

Here's my current solution:

```
make_sound = function(input)
  animal_sounds = {
    ["cat"] = "meow",
    ["dog"] = "woof"
  }

return animal_sounds.input

end

  print(make_sound("cat"))
```

This just  prints 'nil'. I've tried so many variations of this but they all either print 'nil' as well or give me an error saying something about nil (sorry I can't remember the original message or erroneous code).

I know this is a really dumb question and probably has an extremely basic answer so I'm sorry for my stupidity. All the other exercises have been a breeze and then I suddenly get hit with this thing for an hour. I searched everywhere but could only find results about functions inside arrays or something else completely. I didn't want to just give up on a seemingly easy task so here I am...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *If your function returns the whole `animal_sounds` table*, though it is not what is asked of you, you get the animal sound by `print(make_sound().cat)`:

  - `make_sound` is a function,
  - `make_sound()` returns a table,
  - `make_sound()['cat']` is a field of that table,
  - and `make_sound().cat` is syntactic sugar for it, as is said in the answer above.
- Also, better declare everything `local`, including function `make_sound` and `animal_sounds` table.
- And you can skip `[""]`/`['']` in table keys, if they are strings of basic Latin, numbers and underscores: `cat = 'mew'` not `['cat'] = 'mew'`.
- Unless you are going to use `make_sound` as a variable, it is better to declare it with `local function` syntax, rather than an assignment.
- You can skip parentheses around the only string or table parametre in the function call: `f'str'` rather than `f( 'str' )`.
- Most imporantly, your function never uses `input`, which is supposed to be the animal. Therefore, it has to return not the table, but the sound. So, move the `[]` part inside the function.

So:

```lua
local function make_sound( input )
    local animal_sounds = {
        cat = 'meow',
        dog = 'woof',
        cow = 'moo'
    }
    return animal_sounds[input]
end

print( make_sound 'cat' )
```

**P.S.** You can even make the table anonymous, though it will need to be surrounded with parentheses, otherwise Lua will think that `return` is not the last operator before `end` as it should be:

```lua
local function make_sound( input )
    return ({
        cat = 'meow',
        dog = 'woof',
        cow = 'moo'
    })[input]
end

print( make_sound 'cat' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```lua
return animal_sounds[input]
```

The `animal_sounds.input` is equivalent to `animal_sounds["input"]` and your table does not have the `"input"` key, hence it returns `nil`.